# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This command is not available because no document is open

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using code below -I try to save `Word` document file as `.htm`. Can anybody solve this problem?

```
objWord.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, 
                       ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, 
                       ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, 
                       ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing); 
Document oDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument;
oDoc.SaveAs(ref FileToSave, ref fltDocFormat, ref missing, ref missing, 
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: Looks to me like pretty clear message - have you opened your document before doing `save as`? --> `Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");`

Comment: i got error in application.Documents.

Comment: As they say, **show the code**

Comment: actually below code is working in my pc bt on server i got error -System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This command is not available because no document is open.

Comment: Don't ever do this on the server. In any case, you need to open word document at least once before running code like this

Comment: my coding is -  objWord.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing); Document oDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument; oDoc.SaveAs(ref FileToSave, ref fltDocFormat, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by creating Desktop folder in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\
and C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\